# How to enable anti-aliasing in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

Anti-aliasing smooths jagged edges on curved lines and diagonals. How can I enable anti-aliasing on A-Frame?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
<a-scene antialias="true">
```

Note that this does have a performance cost on higher resolution screens, but it is not determined whether that cost is a bottleneck.

Comment: is there anything else need to be done to get more clarity on the scene? This definitely improved the scene but still i can see the effect.

Comment: does nothing as far as i can see :(

Answer (score 4):

I think the previous answer is outdated. It is like this now.

```
<a-scene renderer="antialias: true">
 ...
</a-scene>
```

[Docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/renderer.html)